# Initialization of a pointer

Tags: c++

I am currently confused with the following statement - I though this statement would yield an error during compile time however it doesn't.

```
// statement 1:
someclass* q(someclass());
```

I understand if the statement was like this

```
// statement 2:
someclass* q(&someclass());
```

I would like to know why statment 1 doesnt generate an error or even if that is valid (is there anything I am missing behind the scenes ?)

Comment: Did you try to use the "pointer" in the first example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I would like to know why statment 1 doesnt generate an error or even if that is valid

The first statement is valid, although it is probably not doing what you expect: this statement is declaring a *function* named `q` which returns a pointer to an object of type `someclass` and takes in input a function which in turn accepts no arguments and returns an object of type `someclass`. This is called the [**Most Vexing Parse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

The second statement is not valid: it is trying to declare a pointer named `q` to an object of type `someclass`, and initialize this pointer to the address of the object constructed by the `someclass()` expression. Notice, however, that `someclass()` is a *temporary*, and taking the address of a temporary is illegal.

Comment: For this reason, I would recommend initializing using the `=` operator instead of `()`.  e.g. `someclass* q = someclass();` would create an error as you expect.

Comment: The second statement is not valid.  You *cannot* take the address of a temporary.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Damn, how could I overlook that. Thank you

Comment: Because you've probably seen it work before, most likely in Visual Studio, which warns about it as a non-standard extension, but doesn't error out.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Could be. Thank you anyway, this was a bad mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Statement 1 is actually a declaration for a function. This function is called `q`, and takes a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning a `someclass`, and returns a pointer to `someclass`.

See [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).